# Display the list box over the below text field controls

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel, mixing

Actually I am creating one panel `A` and including the text fields and list box and then created another panel `B` and insert `A` panel to `B`.  Now I have to enter the some text field, but the below list box not visible in that `B` panel.

How to display the list box over the below text fields controls?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are mixing heavy and light components. Read this: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/